# Ecommerce database design?

Tags: database-design, e-commerce

I want to do an ECommerce app. I want to add properties to categories and search them dynamicly category within properties.

I mean:

```
  CATEGORIES             PROPERTIES
| Computer properties  | MotherBoard, GraphicCart etc.
| Phone properties     | Cam, Connecting properties, bluetoot etc.
| Digital Camera       | Zoom option , Lcd, Battery etc.
```

I have allready done this wiht relational tables. This is the way I think:

[image]

So, my question is this way true? Or We have other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have asked a question that cannot be answered by one simple little post on SO. There are some basic design concepts that are fundamental to good database design. There is a lot of thought that goes into this type of activity.

I recommend you read the book ***Database Design for Mere Mortals*** by Michael Hernandez ISBN: 0-201-69471-9. [Amazon Listing](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=0-201-69471-9&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3A0-201-69471-9&enc=1&ajr=4) I noticed he has a second edition.

[Link to Second edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752840)

He walks you through the entire process (from start to finish) of designing a database. I recommend you start with this book.

You have to learn to look at things in groups or chunks. Database design has simple building blocks just like programming does. If you gain a thorough understanding of these simple building blocks you can tackle any database design.

The simpler you make things the better. A database is nothing more than a place where you put data into cubbie holes. Start by identifying what these cubbie holes are and what kind of stuff you want in them.

You are never going to create the perfect database design the first time you try. This is a fact. Your design will go through several refinements during the process. Sometimes things won't seem apparent until you start entering data, and then you have an **ahh ha** moment.

Answer (score 0):

[E-commerce Database Design proposed by Rick Curtis of princeton university](https://www.princeton.edu/~rcurtis/ultradev/ecommdatabase.html)

This link might help you as well as any beginner to build an effective and easy e-commerce database design.